# Add business days to the new date in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add the new date with 1 business day. For example if user select any Friday, it should display Monday's date in the second field. Below is the code:

**Jquery:**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 //<![CDATA[
  $(function () {

   $('.one').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date){
  var date2 = $('.one').datepicker('getDate');
    console.log(date2.getUTCDay());
    if(date2.getUTCDay() == 4)
      date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+3);
    else
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);        
  $('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);
  },
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
  })
  $('.two').datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends})

  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
  currentItem++;
  $('#items').val(currentItem);
  var strToAdd = '<tr><td style=""><input type="text" name="task'+currentItem+'" id="task'+currentItem+'" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" name="Description'+currentItem+'" id="Description'+currentItem+'" value="" /></td><td style="width: 160px;"><input type="text" class="one datepicker" name="Internal_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Internal_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="two datepicker" name="Client_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Client_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="Actual_Deadline'+currentItem+'" id="Actual_Deadline'+currentItem+'" /></td><td style="width:83px;"></td></tr>';
  $('#data').append(strToAdd);
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  });

  //]]>
  </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <TABLE id="data" class="dd" style="">
    <TR>
    <td style=""><input type="text" name="task1" id="task1" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" name="Description1" id="Description1" value="" /></td><td style="width: 160px;"><input type="text" class="one datepicker" name="Internal_Deadline1" id="Internal_Deadline1" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" class="two datepicker" name="Client_Deadline1" id="Client_Deadline1" value="" /></td><td style=""><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="Actual_Deadline1" id="Actual_Deadline1" value="" /></td><td style="width: 83px;"></td></tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="1" /> 
    </TABLE>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following code in your initilization:

```
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47SeR/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to display Monday's date in the second textbox not to comment the saturday and sunday on datepicker

Comment: It is picking Monday if we select Friday in the fiddle. Do you want to select Saturday and Sunday as well?

Comment: No dude, it's displaying Saturday's date in the second textbox when we select Friday from the first textbox.

Comment: Updated the fiddle...sorry for the earlier mistake

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But now the second field become blank. i think it's because of my "add a row" fuctionality. I have edited my question please look into it.

Comment: Hi @user I have updated the fiddle with the code you have over here. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/47SeR/3/

Comment: There is no #addnew button hence that code is not working at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine on first row. It's not working from second row onwards when i'm adding row from <input type="button" id="addnew2" name="addnew2" value="Add a Row" />

Comment: Hi @V31 New date is not displaying on "Client_Deadline" field from second row.

Comment: Finally got it working for the add new row as well :) find the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/47SeR/4/

Comment: Sorry. I need one more help if you can. Now, I want to add 3 from the selected date. I changed your code like this if(date2.getUTCDay() == 4)
      date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+5);
    else
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+3);              It's working correctly but if we select Wednesday then the new date become saturday-it should display monday. The same for when i select Thursday it displaying sunday- it should display Tuesday

Comment: I want remove all weekends. It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: The requirement is if Wednesday to Friday is selected then Monday should come up right?

Comment: No buddy..selected date plus 3 business days. That means if user select Wednesday then it should display monday. For Thursday, it should display Tuesday and for Friday should display Wednesday.